# R dataframe cumsum over rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
df <- data.frame(var=c("A", "B", "C"), 
             "2020-01-01"=c(1,2,3),
             "2020-01-02"=c(1,2,3),
             "2020-01-03"=c(1,2,3))
```

and I would like to calculate the cumulative sum of each variable (on each row), but if I run
`apply(df, 1, cumsum)` it coerces values to `NAs` and if I run `apply(df[,2:4], 1, cumsum)` it gives my back only the matrix output of selected rows and columns (and transposes the output).

Could anybody suggest simple way of transformation such data frames (that have in some columns character values) with cumsum? Im working with `tidyverse`, so any solutions that work with pyping stream, are welcome even more!

So my intended output should look like this:

`var X2020.01.01 X2020.01.02 X2020.01.03
1   A           1           2           2
2   B           2           4           6
3   C           3           6           9`

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already noticed yourself, `apply` yields a transposed output, so just `t`ranspose back again. You could add the result with `data.frame` to a joined data frame; the column names of the `cumsum`s will thereby be extended with `.1`.

```
df <- data.frame(df, t(apply(df[-1], 1, cumsum)))
df
# var X2020.01.01 X2020.01.02 X2020.01.03 X2020.01.01.1 X2020.01.02.1 X2020.01.03.1
# 1   A           1           1           1             1             2             3
# 2   B           2           2           2             2             4             6
# 3   C           3           3           3             3             6             9
```

To get the result of your edit to your question, just do

```
df <- data.frame(t(apply(df[-1], 1, cumsum)))
df
#   X2020.01.01 X2020.01.02 X2020.01.03
# 1           1           2           3
# 2           2           4           6
# 3           3           6           9
```

Comment: Thanks! `cbind(var=df[,1], as.data.frame(t(apply(df[,2:4], 1, cumsum))))` does the work, and if i have more character columns , then selecting does not omit the structure, so I dont even need to `var=` for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Using datatable to melt then dcast the data (effectively transposing it) then cumsum on each column, then transpose it back:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- dcast(melt(
     dcast(melt(dt1, id.vars = "var"), ... ~ var)[, 
       LETTERS[1:3] := cumsum(.SD), .SDcols = LETTERS[1:3]], 
     id.vars = "variable"), ... ~ variable)
```

Gives:

```
> dt1
   variable.1 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-03
1:          A          1          2          3
2:          B          2          4          6
3:          C          3          6          9
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowCumsums` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
df[-1] <- rowCumsums(as.matrix(df[-1]))
```